# Can a player get rewards for Hard difficulty if the mission was already beaten on Easy?

Tags: destiny

When choosing a destination, the difficulty selection becomes available.  When hovering over each, there always seems to be a difference in the amount of XP awarded based on what difficulty you choose.

If you play a level through on Easy, can you later play it on Hard and get the extra XP bonus?  What about other reward differences between difficulties?

Comment: I won't put this as an answer because I'm not 100% sure, but in my experience, no.  You can only get the exp bonus for the first run through of the story missions.

Comment: I don't quite remember... but when I played the *beta*, as @turbo suggested, you only got the xp from the first run-through, regardless of difficulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endgame rewards match the level of the mission/difficulty, but ingame rewards(loot) match *your* level. The first time bonuses (EXP bonus, special items, etc) are all one time bonuses, so if you want 3600 exp instead of 3000 bonus, do the mission on harder difficulties on your first playthrough.